# Empty list in Ravendb index creating exception

Tags: indexing, ravendb, document-database

I have a problem that an `index` I've made when queried is throwing an exception :

> Could not read value for property: Members

Here is the `index` :

```
public class GroupsNameIdIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<CommunityDocument, GroupsNameIdIndex.Result>
    {
        public class Result
        {
            public string CommunityId { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public IList<string> Members { get; set; }
        }

        public GroupsNameIdIndex()
        {
            Map = communities => from community in communities
               from newGroup in community.Groups
                select new
                {
                    CommunityId = community.Id.Replace("CommunityDocuments/", string.Empty),
                    newGroup.Id,
                    newGroup.Name,
                    newGroup.Members
                };
            StoreAllFields(FieldStorage.Yes);
        }
    }
```

This is the query :

```
 var groupResult = session
                .Query<GroupsNameIdIndex.Result, GroupsNameIdIndex>()
                .Where(x => x.CommunityId == info.Id)
                .AsProjection<GroupsNameIdIndex.Result>()
                .ToList();
```

I only have `1` group in the document with relevant `Id` and the Members node is an empty list, not null.  When I manually populate it with a single string, then the query runs fine.  Why are empty lists not allowed?  If this is a restriction, it makes indexing pointless for me, because I will have a lot of empty lists that are just going to make the application fail everywhere.

**edit**: Adding the class in case that has something to do with it:

```
public class CommunityGroup
    {
        public CommunityGroup()
        {
            Members = new List<string>();
            MemberDetails = new List<MemberView>();
            MemberNames = new List<string>();
        }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool AdminOnly { get; set; }
        public bool NewsContribute { get; set; }
        public bool AutoGroup { get; set; }
        public int LowerAgeLimit { get; set; }
        public int UpperAgeLimit { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public IList<string> Members { get; set; }
        public IList<string> MemberNames { get; set; }
        public IList<MemberView> MemberDetails { get; set; }
        public string RelatedCommunityId { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public bool SmartGroup { get; set; }
        public IList<SmartGroupRules> AndRules { get; set; }
        public IList<SmartGroupRules> OrRules { get; set; }
        public string ParentGroup { get; set; }
        public List<string> EntryGroups { get; set; }
        public bool Hidden { get; set; }
        public string ActivityType { get; set; }
        public List<string> AnyGroupList { get; set; }
        public List<string> AllGroupList { get; set; }
        public GroupType GroupType { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is the json of the group in the db

```
   "Groups": [
        {
            "Id": "5ja34tefoq7sfj",
            "Name": "new test",
            "Slug": "new-test",
            "Description": null,
            "AdminOnly": true,
            "NewsContribute": false,
            "AutoGroup": false,
            "LowerAgeLimit": 0,
            "UpperAgeLimit": 0,
            "Gender": null,
            "Members": [],
            "MemberNames": [],
            "MemberDetails": [],
            "RelatedCommunityId": null,
            "CreatedBy": "Activity",
            "SmartGroup": false,
            "AndRules": null,
            "OrRules": null,
            "ParentGroup": null,
            "EntryGroups": null,
            "Hidden": false,
            "ActivityType": null,
            "AnyGroupList": null,
            "AllGroupList": null,
            "GroupType": "Default"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: What is the full error?

Comment: Inner exception is 'Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject.'. Stack trace is here: http://textuploader.com/dfx8m

Comment: which version of ravendb?

Comment: its version 3.5

Comment: .AsProjection should be an extension method of previous versions of ravendb, i tried your code with .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto and it works

Comment: ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto  doesn't work either. I've added in the class and json for the data in case there's something wrong there. Just to reiterate, as soon as I add a string item into the 'Members' node, then it works.  Very confusing issue.